# How to create curved lines connecting nodes in D3

Tags: d3.js

I would like to create a graphic in D3 that consists of nodes connected to each other with curved lines. The lines should be curved differently depending on how far apart the start and end point of the line are.

[image]

For example (A) is a longer connection and therefore is less curved than (C).

Which D3 function is best used for this calculation and how is it output as SVG path

A code example (for example on [observablehq.com](https://observablehq.com/)) would help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code example in obserbavlehq.com
https://observablehq.com/@garciaguillermoa/circles-and-links

I will try to explain it, let me know if there is something I am not clear enough:

Lets start with our circles, we use `d3.pie()` to position this circles, passing the data defined above, it will return us some arcs, but as we want circles instead of arcs, we use `arc.centroid` to get the coordinates of our circles

Value is required for the spacing in the pie layout that we use to calculate the position, if you want more circles, you will need to reduce the value, here is the related code:

```
pie = d3
  .pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value((d) => {
    return d.value;
  });

arc = d3.arc().outerRadius(300).innerRadius(50);

data = [
  { id: 0, value: 10 },
  { id: 1, value: 10 },
  { id: 2, value: 10 },
  { id: 3, value: 10 },
  { id: 4, value: 10 },
  { id: 5, value: 10 },
  { id: 6, value: 10 },
  { id: 7, value: 10 },
  { id: 8, value: 10 },
  { id: 9, value: 10 },
];

const circles = [];
for(let item of pieData) {
  const [x, y] = arc.centroid(item);
  circles.push({x, y});
}
```

Now we can render the circles:

```
const svg = d3.create("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

const mainGroup = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("id", "main")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

// Insert lines and circles groups, lines first so they are behind circles
const linesGroup = mainGroup.append("g").attr("id", "lines");
const circlesGroup = mainGroup.append("g").attr("id", "circles");

circlesGroup
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles, (_, index) => index)
  .join((enter) => {
    enter
      .append("circle")
      .attr("id", (_, index) => {
        return `circle-${index}`;
      })
      .attr("r", 20)
      .attr("cx", (d) => {
        return d.x;
      })
      .attr("cy", (d) => {
        return d.y;
      })
      .style("stroke-width", "2px")
      .style("stroke", "#000")
      .style("fill", "#963cff");
  });
```

Now we need to declare the links, we could do this with an array specifying the id of the source and destination (from and to). we use this to search each circle, get its coordinates (the source and destination of our links) and then create the links, in order to create them, we can use a path and the d3 method `quadraticCurveTo`, this function requires four parameters, the first two are "the control point" which defines our curve, we use 0, 0 as it is the center of our viz (it is the center because we used a translate in the parent group).

```
lines = [
  {
    from: 1,
    to: 3,
  },
  {
    from: 8,
    to: 4,
  },
];

for (let line of lines) {
  const fromCircle = circles[line.from];
  const toCircle = circles[line.to];

  const fromP = { x: fromCircle.x, y: fromCircle.y };
  const toP = { x: toCircle.x, y: toCircle.y };

  const path = d3.path();
  path.moveTo(fromP.x, fromP.y);
  path.quadraticCurveTo(0, 0, toP.x, toP.y);

  linesGroup
    .append("path")
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", "10 10")
    .style("stroke", "#000")
    .attr("d", path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Guillermo. It helps me moving forward.